# Impact of Android Customizations by device manufacturers

Tags: android

I am trying to write an android application that uses several of the android apis(like policy manager, package manager, wifi apis etc).

The concern i have is, android being open, manufacturers/carriers are free to take any specific version of android as their start point and customize the same and ship it with the device.

Note:Please excuse me if this post is in anyway a repeat of earlier posts on the same/similar topic. In such a case, appreciate anyone sharing the earlier post.

Few things that bother me are:

- Does android enforce/require manufacturers/carriers to retain the default apis and only over-ride/customize the look-and-feel?
- even if manufacturers change the implementation/behavior of the basic apis that comes from android, do they adhere to the interfaces so that my code doesnt break?
- how do i ensure/test that my code works on all of the android devices since there is a possibility that one or more customizations could break my whole application?

I know these are some naive questions for many of you who may have been on android for a while, but any pointers in this regard would be of immense help.

Any other information in general w.r.t cross version, cross device incompatibilities and strategies to deal with them would be very helpful.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

Your concerns (and many other developers) are addressed by: http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html
But this still does not guarantee that manufacturer will not change API and break your application.

The common approach is to initially target subset of devices that make up large percentage of market and then implement workaround for other devices (if necessary). Sample info about device market penetration can be found at:
http://opensignalmaps.com/reports/fragmentation.php?

Kind regards,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

First off, I don't believe you should need to worry about this.  Only after you have thousands of users will you end up needing to face the more complex issues caused by the great number of manufacturers offering Android devices.  This should not discourage you from developing for Android.

- Does android enforce/require manufacturers/carriers to retain the default apis and only over-ride/customize the look-and-feel?

  - No.  But it would certainly work against them if they remove important APIs from the system.  The core exists as a whole, though there really isn't anything preventing them from removing or disabling chunks as they wish.  For example, AT&T had disabled the ability to sideload apps on Android devices some time ago (but I don't think they still do that).  An example of a device with reduced functionality:  Amazon Kindle Fire.  It doesn't at all look like Android in the majority of its interfaces (except within third-party apps) and it doesn't offer the complete API set.  Even with those dramatic changes, Android app developers still have great success building and selling apps that run well on the Kindle Fire.
- Even if manufacturers change the implementation/behavior of the basic apis that comes from android, do they adhere to the interfaces so that my code doesnt break?

  - That's the idea, but there isn't anything in place to forbid them from breaking things.  Nor is there anything that will keep them from introducing bugs accidentally.
- How do I ensure/test that my code works on all of the android devices since there is a possibility that one or more customizations could break my whole application?

  - I know that some manufacturers will offer an emulator for their devices/configurations to help test against their systems.  For example, Motorola offers MOTODEV Studio for this purpose.

Comment: To follow up on @DustyWilson and clarify...  MOTODEV Studio is Eclipse with some things added to make development easier.  One of the tools we provide in the package is called "App Validator" and it has some checks to ensure that display fragmentation isn't an issue in your app.  If you want to try your app on our SDK addons (emulator images), use the SDK Manager from the Android SDK to download and install to your system.  The API fragmentation you're concerned about is covered by the CTS.